# Javascript Event.originalEvent.path IE8 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

This code is for collapsing a panel in bootstrap.
`e.originalEvent.path` in IE is not working.

```
$(document).on('click', '.panel-heading.clickable', function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if($(e.originalEvent.path[0]).attr("href") != "#" && $(e.originalEvent.path[0]).is("a") && !$this.hasClass('panel-collapsed')){
            return false;
        }
        if (!$this.hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
            $this.parent().children('.panel-body').slideUp();
            $this.addClass('panel-collapsed');
            $this.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
        } else {
            $this.parent().children('.panel-body').slideDown();
            $this.removeClass('panel-collapsed');
            $this.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
        }
    }
);
```

It is working on google chrome but in IE it does not work.
Is there available workaround for e.originalEvent.path?
Thanks!

Comment: bootstrap version used

Comment: The [originalEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/originalTarget) is a non standard feature which may not have wide support especially in older browsers... what are you trying to do here

Comment: I'm trying to check if the event is trigger on an a tag and the href value should not be `href != #` to proceed for collapsing a panel..,

I use bootstrap 3.x.

Comment: any good alternatives for originalEvent in ie8?

Comment: Hi @SuperUberDuper, you can use e.target for IE 8 alternative for e.originalEvent.., You can explore those event properties.,. :-)